# What does an answer with a score of zero with up-votes and down-votes do for Unsung Hero?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting, zero-voted-posts

If I have an answer that has equal up-votes and down-votes so it looks like zero votes:

[image]

And the answer is accepted does that get me closer to the [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) badge? I would think so because of the description: "Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total", but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Did you checkout this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97937/do-negative-score-accepted-answers-count-towards-tenacious-unsung-hero/97940#97940

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is yes, [that does count to the Unsung Hero/Tenacious badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97940/):

> We check the net score, so a post with 1 upvote and 1 downvote would qualify as a "zero score" answer. A negatively downvoted post with a net negative would not qualify.

Comment: you should link to the quote,  Don't trust that Manoj's comment will always be there